# cone and its scaled image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra

Let $C$ be a polyhedral cone in $\mathbb{R}^m$ defined by

$C = \{R y : y \in \mathbb{R}^m_+\}$ and $R\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

Let $S: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$, be a scaling map, i.e. $S = \text{diag}(v)$ for some vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^m_+$, and $C' = \{ S x : x \in C \}$ be the image of the cone $C$ by $S$.
Consider that $v_i\leq v_{i+1}$.

What are the conditions on $R$ such that $C'\subset C$ ?

It seems sufficient to have $R$ block lower-triangular with $R_{ij}=0$ when $\alpha_i < \alpha_j$, but I could not show whether it is necessary.